# Apache2 not asking for password of private SSL key

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, openssl

I am trying to set up SSH for my apache2 server. Apache seems to find my private key, because it complains once I move it. But it doesn't check the content of the file: When I replace it with gibberish, it will still give me a nice startup

```
ks@survey:/etc/apache2/ssl.key$ sudo service apache2 restart
[ ok ] Restarting web server: apache2 ... waiting .
```

Shouldn't it be checking the content of the key file and asking me for my password?
Here is what my error.log says:

```
[Wed Jul 23 22:21:55 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jul 23 22:21:56 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

(My version of openssl is supposed to be patched and free of heartbleed.)

Apachectl gives the following output:

```
ks@survey:/etc/init.d$ sudo  /usr/sbin/apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          survey.zqa.tu-dresden.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/workload-ssl:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server survey.zqa.tu-dresden.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/workload:1)
         port 80 namevhost survey.zqa.tu-dresden.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/workload:1)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: What's your configuration look like? What problems are there with the SSL listener when you try to use it?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Here is my configuration: http://pastebin.com/LH2rGMH8

Comment: @ShaneMadden How do I use the SSL listener? What exactly are you referring to? (I'm sorry, this is all new to me, I'll try to google a bit in order to etter understand your quesion)

Comment: I mean the config file that contains the SSL virtual host.  By "using" the SSL listener, I mean, trying to connect to it in a browser.. if it's failing to load configured SSL keys, it should be erroring, so what it's doing with port 443 (listening or not, with an SSL key or not) is potentially relevant.  Also, can you edit your question to add the output of `apachectl -S`?

Comment: My configuration: http://pastebin.com/715x8YrJ

Comment: @ShaneMadden I don't have `apachectl` and somehow I can't install it. I have debian and `httpd` is not available. Maybe this here helps: http://pastebin.com/eeLMNLBX ?

Comment: What method did you use to install Apache?  The file in init.d should show the path to the httpd binary; once you have that, run `/path/to/bin/httpd -S`.  Also, verify that the key and cert match - compare the modulus from the output of `openssl x509 -noout -text -in /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/cert-6728091434395901.pem` and `openssl rsa -noout -text -in /etc/apache2/ssl.key/server-key.pem`.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I either installed apache2 via apt-get or it came with the server and the debian installation, I don't remember. The file init.d/apache2 does not contain the string `httpd`:http://pastebin.com/sARSgJvs     The moduli are equal, but I don't think it's an issue with the keys anyway since replacing the private key file with gibberish doesn't even throw an error.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/apache2`.  Are you logged in as root?  `apachectl` is likely at `/usr/sbin/apachectl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/workload-ssl` on line 2 is the config you pastebinned, right?

Add `SSLEngine On` to the `<VirtualHost>` block there.

Comment: Yes, it is. Ok, I'll try to put it in the right place and report back here.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. It is now asking me for password. And ssl seems to be working on the website. This is my first time. http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ldp0jmKIrZ1qzsln6.gif

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the ssl in the apache modules? If not, you have to execute:

```
a2enmod ssl
```

Then if the ssl site is not enabled, you have to execute:

```
a2ensite default-ssl
```

You also have to modify the ports.conf.

Comment: I have manually linked my ssl configuration file in `sites-available` and adding a typo there induces an appropriate error message, so I assume this is being checked. If I do this I don't need to call `a2enmod`, correct?

Comment: My  ports.conf looks like this http://pastebin.com/dvZwipkM and here is a link to my system configuration overview http://pastebin.com/LH2rGMH8